# Leave management system hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a project and I use hibernate and javafx and I have a question about a leave management system.

How can I get specific sum of days that someone take without counting holidays in hql?

I have two tables:

table "Conge ":

```
integer id,
integer nombre_jour,
LocalDate date_debut,
LocalDate date_fin,
String type,
Personnel personnel
```

table "Personnel":

```
Integer id,
String nom,
String prenom,
String cin,
String nb_jours_par_annee,
LocalDate date_embauche;
```

query:

```
query:select sum(C.nombre_jour) from 
Conge C 
where C.date_debut=:date_debut 
    and C.date_fin=:date_fin 
    and C.id_personnel=:id
```

but how can I get days that someone took without counting holidays?

Comment: Please write database tables and query have written so far to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In leave management software, you typically have a place where you define a calendar of days that are deemed non-workable.

It is important to note that you may need to support defining multiple calendar configurations that depend upon varying criteria such as the employee's department, their job assignment, and/or their location.  For example, an office worker working in the United States would have a differing holiday exemption schedule than an employee working in the same department doing the same job but be based in Germany.

Your calculation basically becomes

```
NumberOfDays( end - start ) - NumberOfHolidaysInclusive( empId, start, end )
```

The idea with the `NumberOfDays` if quite simple, calculate the number of days between the two dates.  The idea with `NumberOfHolidaysInclusive` is to lookup the appropriate calendar based on the employee id, `empId` and based on that calendar get the number of exclusions within the date range including the start and end dates (e.g. inclusive).

How you write that in HQL / JPQL / SQL depends heaily on your schema, but the premise remains the same.